# REACT Dynamic Routing advice needed - redirect url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<Route 
   exact 
   path="/product"
   render={this.renderProduct}
/>

<Route 
   exact 
   path="/product/:productId"
   render={this.renderProductApp}
/>
```

We have created some dynamic urls using React-router.

Among these product Ids I want to redirect a specifc product id url **/product/param1** to **/product/param2**
where param1 and param2 are some product Ids(like kindle, etc)

Please advise as I'm new to React.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, routes should be wrapped inside `<Switch/>`, otherwise it would render all routes which is matched. For you case, you can place the `<Redirect/>` on top of the product route. So the possible solution would be:

```js
<Switch>
  <Redirect from="/product/ipad" to="/product/kindle"/>
  <Route 
     exact 
     path="/product"
     render={this.renderProduct}
  />
  <Route 
     exact 
     path="/product/:productId"
     render={this.renderProductApp}
  />
</Switch>
```

If some one does not want to use the `exact` props, swapping the route location is needed. This is because `Switch` component matches only the first path that matches the current location. Another possible solution would be:

```js
<Switch>
  <Redirect from="/product/ipad" to="/product/kindle"/>
  <Route 
     path="/product/:productId"
     render={this.renderProductApp}
  />
  <Route 
     path="/product"
     render={this.renderProduct}
  />
</Switch>
```